# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, winreg

I'm not sure why I am getting an `invalid syntax` error on this. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import _winreg

explorer = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer"
    )

# list values owned by this registry key
try:
    i = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = _winreg.EnumValue(explorer, i)
        print repr(name),
        i += 1
except WindowsError:
    print

value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(explorer, "Logon User Name")

print
print "user is", repr(value)
```

Comment: Exactly, what gives you syntax error? Ps. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Is this Python 3? If so, [print](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function now.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code to work on Python3, change the 3 lines with print as follows

```
import _winreg

explorer = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer"
    )

# list values owned by this registry key
try:
    i = 0
    while 1:
        name, value, type = _winreg.EnumValue(explorer, i)

        # end="" means no new line
        print(repr(name), end="")

        i += 1
except WindowsError:
    print

value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(explorer, "Logon User Name")

print()
print("user is", repr(value))
```